# Apache-Spark: export the data from the history server

Tags: apache-spark

A simple question, how can I export the data from the history server?. I want to export only the main page, that has the general info of all the applications.

App ID, App Name, Started, Completed, Duration, Spark User, Last Updated

My goal is to create a CSV with the same structure.

Regards!

Comment: I don't believe there is out of the box solution for this. At least, I'm not aware of one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The history server has a REST API, similar to the Spark UI's [REST API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api).

Try this url: `http://localhost:18080/api/v1/applications`. Maybe you have to adopt the server and port to your installation. The REST API will a return a Json document.

Answer (score 0):

or you can use a web scraper like data miner and skip  the API hell